# Next.js 13 next.config.js "port" attribute for remotePatterns doesn't work for Image component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The below code snippet doesn't work. I'm trying to use remotePatterns in my next.config.js file to allow external images. If I change port to an empty string "", it works. When I specify "443" it doesn't work. I've no idea why. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

```
---
page.tsx:

import Image from "next/image";

function Homepage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Image
        src="https://not-real-url.com/wp-content/uploads/not-real-logo.png"
        width={50}
        height={50}
        alt="An image"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Homepage;

---
next.config.js:

module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "not-real-url.com",
        port: "443",
        pathname: "/wp-content/uploads/*",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Port 443 is already used for SSL I think.

Comment: But remotePatterns is an indication of where images are allowed to be pulled from. 443 is naturally HTTPS so I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use the port, the port is only needed when you will be calling it in the URL, for example `someserver.com:5000`, they you have to make sure you add the port. What I think is that you have to leave it empty, and maybe what you should do is add double asterisk in your pathname, like `pathname: "/wp-content/uploads/**",`.